# Applications menu

Tags: lxde

Would deleting any of the .desktop files in the applications folder to remove them from the start menu mess up any thing else or would it just remove them from the menu.

Or is there away of hiding category's on the menu

Raspbian

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have something directly referencing the .desktop file, it should be fine to delete it. I don't see the need of doing this though.

Comment: To remove programs form the start menu so that students don't have a over crowded menu